# Getting the values of a collection objects within an object in an appsettings.json file in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

I have a .NET Core application and I have the following in my appsettings.json file:

```
"PaymentGateways": {
    "CroutonStripe": {
      "ApiBasePath": "url",
      "XApiKey": "apikey",
      "LinesOfBusiness": [
        {
          "Name": "odb",
          "WebhookSecretKey": "key1"
        },
        {
          "Name": "dh",
          "WebhookSecretKey": "key2"
        }
      ],
      "CreatePostUrl": "url",
      "UpdatePostUrl": "url"
    }
  }
```

I have the following in my Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.Configure<CroutonStripePaymentGatewayOptions>(options =>
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("PaymentGateways").GetSection("CroutonStripe").Bind(options));
```

In my constructor I have the following:

```
    public MyController(
        IOptions<CroutonStripePaymentGatewayOptions> options)
    {
        LineOfBusinesses = options.Value.LineOfBusinesses;
    }
```

When I run it LineOfBusinesses is null.  If I have a string array I found that the string array has the values correctly from the appsettings file and all other string properties on CroutonStripePaymentGatewayOptions class have the correct values from the appsettings file.

But I was able to get the values by adding the following to Program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<List<LineOfBusiness>>(options =>
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("PaymentGateways").GetSection("CroutonStripe").GetSection("LinesOfBusiness").Bind(options));
```

and the following to my constructor:

```
    public MyController(
        IOptions<CroutonStripePaymentGatewayOptions> options,
        IOptions<List<Gateway.LineOfBusiness>> lineOfBusoinessesOptions)
    {
        LineOfBusinesses = lineOfBusoinessesOptions.Value;
    }
```

```
public class CroutonStripePaymentGatewayOptions
{
    public string ApiBasePath { get; set; }
    public string XApiKey { get; set; }
    public List<LineOfBusiness> LineOfBusinesses { get; set; }
    public string CreatePostUrl { get; set; }
    public string UpdatePostUrl { get; set; }
}

public class LineOfBusiness
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string WebhookSecretKey { get; set; }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a way to get .NET Core to return the values of the LineOfBussinesses collection within the options parameter in my constructor.

Comment: can you show the `CroutonStripePaymentGatewayOptions` class ?

Comment: I have added the code to the CroutonStripePaymentGatewayOptions class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the property name is wrong, your property should be `LinesOfBusiness` not `LineOfBusinesses`

so your `CroutonStripePaymentGatewayOptions` should be :

```cs
public class CroutonStripePaymentGatewayOptions
{
    public string ApiBasePath { get; set; }
    public string XApiKey { get; set; }
    public List<LineOfBusiness> LinesOfBusiness { get; set; }
    public string CreatePostUrl { get; set; }
    public string UpdatePostUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Renaming my property to LinesOfBusiness resolved this.  Thanks.